# Select the greatest value from each column, even if one of the values is null

Tags: oracle, select, oracle-12c, null

I have a `road_age_test` table:

```
create table road_age_test (
    surface_year int,
    base_year int
);

insert into road_age_test (surface_year, base_year) values (10,20);
insert into road_age_test (surface_year, base_year) values (30,null);
insert into road_age_test (surface_year, base_year) values (null,40);
insert into road_age_test (surface_year, base_year) values (null,null);
insert into road_age_test (surface_year, base_year) values (50,50);

commit;

select * from road_age_test;

SURFACE_YEAR  BASE_YEAR
------------ ----------
          10         20
          30       null    
        null         40
        null       null
          50         50
```

I would like to select the greatest value from each column, even if one of the values is null:

```
GREATEST_YEAR
-------------
           20
           30
           40
         null
           50
```

What's the simplest way to do this?

---

Note: Where both values are `null`, I want to return `null`, **not `0`**.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
select
GREATEST(nvl(surface_year,0),nvl(base_year,0)) as greatest_year
from
road_age_test;

--Edit using NULLIF 
select
NULLIF(GREATEST(nvl(surface_year,0),nvl(base_year,0)),0) as greatest_year
from
road_age_test;

--Adding a segmented version for readability (some find it worse, eye of the beholder I guess)
select
NULLIF(
    GREATEST(
            nvl(surface_year,0),
            nvl(base_year,0) --Just keep adding columns here if you need to
            )
      ,0) as greatest_year
from
road_age_test;
```

Can't imagine it's much more efficient (and shouldn't be used in a where clause due to indexing), but it's a little cleaner than the case statement and allows you to add more values (columns) easily.

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions060.htm

Comment: @Wilson I've updated it to use NULLIF for that scenario.  let me know if that works.

Comment: The part about *'allows you to add more values (columns) easily'* is key!

Comment: @Wilson Agreed!

Comment: MguerraTorres : Someone posted an answer and tried to alert you.

Answer (score 4):

Re: MguerraTorres answer, I don't have the rep to comment:

If you are using 11g or higher, you could define a virtual column, which can be indexed and used in queries (among other things).

```
create table road_age_test (
    surface_year int,
    base_year int,
    greatest_year number generated always as
 (nullif(greatest(nvl(surface_year,0), nvl(base_year,0)),0) ) virtual
);

insert into road_age_test (surface_year, base_year) values (10,20);
insert into road_age_test (surface_year, base_year) values (30,null);
insert into road_age_test (surface_year, base_year) values (null,40);
insert into road_age_test (surface_year, base_year) values (null,null);
insert into road_age_test (surface_year, base_year) values (50,50);

commit;

select greatest_year from road_age_test;


GREATEST_YEAR
-------------
   20
   30
   40

   50

5 rows selected.

create index greatest_year_idx on road_age_test(greatest_year);

Index created.

select greatest_year from road_age_test
where GREATEST_YEAR > 30

GREATEST_YEAR
-------------
       40
       50

2 rows selected.
```

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/statements_7002.htm#BABIJABG

Comment: looks great.  I'm on 10g so I don't have Virtuals.  Nice work.

Answer (score 0):

I can do this with a case statement, if I convert the nulls to zeros:

```
select
    case 
        when nvl(surface_year,0) > nvl(base_year,0) then surface_year
        else base_year 
    end as greatest_year
from
    road_age_test

GREATEST_YEAR
-------------
           20
           30
           40
         null
           50
```

However, this seems like a bit of a **clumsy** approach. Is there a simpler way?

Comment: I can't think of a reason why that's a bad approach.  If you were using that in a where clause,however, then I'd have a different opinion.

Comment: To add, there is a GREATEST function you can use as well. https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions060.htm Example: SELECT GREATEST(1,2,4,6, NVL(NULL,0))
FROM DUAL